# Can not use System.Drawing.Bitmap on Mac: System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, bitmap, xamarin.ios, system.drawing

I'm using a Mac and i must use `Bitmap` class from `System.Drawing` in my Xamarin.iOS project, I try to initialize it but when I do this I get this kind of error.

`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.`

I do not know why this happens *I think* it's because I'm running this code on my Mac *(unsupported platform?)*, but it used to work when I wanted to, but now it doesn't.
To make it clear, I added reference to `System.Drawing` in my project, but it did not change anything.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("./my/path/to/image.png");
```

The code above throws mentioned earlier error. As I written earlier it is a Xamarin.iOS project, on a console project this code is working smoothly.

Comment: Are you able to use ImageSharp instead, perhaps? https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Comment: System.Drawing is heavily tied to Win32 and not available on other platforms (there are a few stub classes implement as helpers, but not the full library).  For cross platform imaging use SkiaSharp

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skpixmap.scalepixels?view=skiasharp-1.68.2